# Tem como trocar o valor de um parâmetro de uma querystring em javascript?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, querystring

Por exemplo tenho essa querystring `www.meusite.com.br?parametro=1`. Eu queria trocar o valor 1 por outro valor quando uma determinada função for chamada, sem precisar carregar a página novamente (se possível).

Comment: você já tem montada essa querystring no javascript ? se tiver poste por favor

Comment: Não tenho não, estou usando asp.net c# e faço o redirect por ele

Comment: É mais fácil você passar via POST ou guardar em cookies do que usar a query

Comment: está muito vago..  `www.meusite.com.br?parametro=1` vem de onde?  é o endereço da barra de url? é uma string? ,enfim..

Answer (score 2):

Para mudar a URL via javascript seria assim:

```
var Url = window.location.host;
document.location = Url + "?parametro=2"; //muda o valor de "parametro" para 2
```

Porém não é possível alterar a URL sem fazer reload da página, isso é uma restrição de segurança.

Imagina que o utilizador recebe um e-mail falso como se fosse de um banco, clica em um botão e é enviado para uma página falsa mas que logo a seguir a URL é alterada para o endereço verdadeiro do banco. O utilizador preenche os dados de login e via `ajax` são gravados em uma base de dados e logo a seguir o redireciona para página verdadeira. Seria uma falha de segurança grave!

Apesar de existir outras formas de detectar se a URL é falsa, a maioria dos utilizadores não sabem como faze-lo.

Comment: Filipe uma dúvida, e se por exemplo, eu já tenha o parâmetro = 1, e precisar trocar para 2.... ele vai trocar o valor ou vai adicionar um novo parâmetro ?

Comment: Depende do que vc fizer! No exemplo que dei altera o valor porque é feito uma concatenação com a URL.

Comment: Então, mas por exemplo, supondo que a url seja `www.meusite.com.br?parametro=1` e ai eu execute o seu código, a url não ficaria `www.meusite.com.br?parametro=1&parametro=2` ?

Comment: @LucasSousa não, ficaria www.meusite.com.br?parametro=2, fiz uma alteração no exemplo da resposta, veja se agora funciona.